# NodeJS request fetch pdf file and save on disk but opens as blank white page

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, post, request

I am fetching a pdf file and want to save that on disk. Below is my code:

```
request.post({
  url: some_api_url,
  json: true,
  body: {
    by: user,
    password: 'mypassword'
  }
}, function(err, response, body) {
  if (err) next(err);
  else {
    if (typeof(body) == 'string') {
      //console.log(body);
      fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'abc.pdf'), body, 'binary', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
    } else {
      console.log("invalid file");
    }
  }
});
```

This saves the pdf on disk with the right size (about 200kb) which means that there is data in body of the post request. However, the pdf opens up blank in document viewer in Ubuntu.

I have also compared "cat abd.pdf | less" outputs of a working pdf file (which opens fine) and the one downloaded through the request and top and bottom of both are same.

Below is the api code that serves the pdf file. If I make the request in postman, the pdf file downloads and save to disk and opens up fine.

```
let fileStat = fs.statSync(filePath);

res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="report.pdf"',
  'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
  'Content-Length': fileStat.size
});

let readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
res.on('finish', function() {
  console.log("file sent");
});
readStream.pipe(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing my solution in case anyone needs it.

The problem was in encoding while reading the file and sending it. Now I am reading the file as base64, transmitting and then again saving from base64 and now it works fine.

Comment: Soo where is the Code to your solution then?